DocuSign - get delegation user after envelope creation
I have users that enabled delegations from preferences in a docusign portal.
Also, i have a connect configuration (Aggregate) but doesn't have "Recipient Delegate" option available for selection.
I tried to create a new one (SIM) with only one "Recipient Delegate" trigger event option but never triggered.
I tried to get envelope also from API but return old recipient.
How can i get the new delegated user instantly after envelope creation ?
Thanks!

Hi Mich,
Thank you for contacting Docusign Developer Support.  We require more information to be able to troubleshoot your issue.
Can you please open a new Support Case with all relevant detail. To do so follow the below link and click on "Open a Support Case":
https://support.docusign.com/s/contactSupport?language=en_US
Reach out and we will be happy to continue investigating.
Best regards,
Conar | Docusign Developer Support

Hi @cbsdsdevsup , its a generic issue and not an envelope specific. If i have a user with delegation, webhook connection doesn't return delegated user but initial recipient.

The delegated recipient data may not be included in the webhook notification.
If not, do an Envelopes.get, and look at the recipient attributes in the response to see if the data is there.
Use the include=recipients query parameter. Eg:
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}?include=recipients


Hi , i don't want to get the 'sender'. I want to get delegated recipients.

Oops, misread your question. I updated my answer.

We have tried your approach. We used "Get envelope" as you mentioned but if delegated signer hasn't made any action (open-sign envelope) the returned recipient is the original and not the delegated.

The delegation hasn't "happened" until the envelope routing reaches the recipient. At that point, I believe the recipient's status becomes "sent" and the delegation info should be populated. Please test.

Hi again, when recipient status becomes "sent" DocuSign keep return old recipient. When the status changed to delivered - declined - completed i get new delegated recipient.

Thank you @G.Mich for checking. I've asked the engineering team to see if there are other options.

Do you have any update from the engineering team ?

No internal response. I'm escalating
